# School test grader

Tags: python

I have tried to write a code where you simply type your test score (out of 100) and it gives you a grade (A,B,C,D..etc). However the code I have written, for some reason, gives me the wrong grade when I give it a random number. for example, I typed 6 and it give me a D (instead of a U).
Here is my code:

```
score=int(input("What score did you get on your test?"))

if int(0)>=score<=int(39):   
    print ("You have got a U in your test.")
elif int(40)>=score<=int(49):    
    print ("You have got a D in your test.")
elif int(50)>=score<= int(59):  
    print ("You have got a C in your test.")
elif int(60)>=score<= int(69):    
    print ("You have got a B in your test.")
else:
    ("You have got an A in your test, well done!")
```

Comment: You don't need `int(39)` all those numbers, they are already int literals.

Comment: And that last line should probably have a `print`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inequalities are incorrect. Currently, the condition for U is

```
if score is smaller than 0 and smaller than 39
```

It should be

```
if score is greater than 0 and smaller than 39
```

so

```
if int(0) <= score <= int(39)
```

However, you can simplify all of your code a considerable amount, as others have pointed out. You can remote the double-sided inequalities and replace them with single ones, remove the `int` conditions, since you're not expecting any non-ints (the numbers 39, 49 etc. are hardcoded), and you should also add an error message of some kind for any grades below 0 or above 100 (currently, they return a U and A respectively, but it should really be an error).

A better solution:

```
score=int(input("What score did you get on your test?"))

if score < 0:
    print("How did you manage to get less than zero?!")
elif score <= 39:
    print ("You have got a U in your test.")
elif score <= 49:    
    print ("You have got a D in your test.")
elif score <= 59:  
    print ("You have got a C in your test.")
elif score <= 69:    
    print ("You have got a B in your test.")
elif score <= 100:
    print ("You have got an A in your test, well done!")
else
    print ("This isn't a valid grade, it should be between 0 and 100!")
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, literally just added those :)